# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS boot aborted (initramfs)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, initramfs

[updated pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJijC.jpg)I am pretty new on Ubuntu and at first my disk drives were too full to even plug in a USB with a small item and files wouldn't let me even see the contents. Now after turning it off and back on (thinking I should find a way to clear the whole drive, and find a way to reinstall it) I get to the Grub menu and clicked on the first one, not the advanced option, and when it started booting normally I get this: [this is what happens after startup without me typing anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht7Zz.jpg)

I even tried typing exit and it gave me this: [the picture I was able to take but it has a whole other page of stuff similar to this right after typing exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1oc8.jpg)

So after trying that I was looking online and tried alot of things but still just no commands found, but I found this command ( cat /proc/partitions ) and this is what it gave me:[cat /proc/partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzuC6.jpg)

Comment: I had Ubuntu already installed but now I can't even get into the login page, when I was last on my home screen my files didn't switch to my new username and even if I tried to delete files it says I can't because it's too full. What I noticed is that it says my driver isn't there. And since I'm stuck on this screen I'm at a loss of what next..what I want to do is wipe everything and restart the installation of Ubuntu

Comment: But how do I get passed this point? It says the drivers not there, and when I try to enter anything to move the files over or anything to do with root it says permission denied.take a look at the picture I posted in the first highlighted words. My driver is full completely so I can't do much until I erase it all, even then idk what commands to do

Comment: I literally can't because I don't have any room to delete and don't have a USB with Ubuntu on it to upload. ( Failed to import pool 'rpool'         Manually import the pool and exit)